# In Windows 7 Process Explorer, what's the equivalent of "VM Size"?

Tags: windows, windows-7, windows-xp

In the process explorer in the task manager, there used to be something called "VM Size" that indicated the amount of less-frequently-used swap disk space used by the app. In Windows 7 process explorer, it doesn't seem to exist. I'm wondering if the equivalent is "private bytes" or "paged data" something something. Any ideas?

- **EDIT:** I know what VM is. Just need to know what the equivalent process explorer column name is in Windows 7.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty certain that you're interested in the Working Set value. As I understand it, Working Set is the full set of virtual memory pages allocated to and referenced by your application. The Private Bytes value tells you the memory currently allocated (or used by, not sure which or if there's a difference) to your application on the private heap (e.g. by malloc() calls).

Check out [this page on SysInternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb469930), especially the [Windows SysInternals Primer](http://www.msteched.com/2010/NorthAmerica/WCL314). I haven't watched it in a while, which is why I'm less certain as to what the private bytes indicate, but I'm pretty certain that's the video where I learned how to read the data coming into ProcExp.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7954781/whats-the-difference-between-working-set-and-commit-size  contradicts this?

Answer (score 1):

I think in Windows 7, "Working Set" corresponds to "Mem Usage", and "Commit Size" corresponds to VM size.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really an expert when it comes to Windows but I think VM stands for virtual memory. Perhaps this [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory) helps.

**Edit**
On the [Microsoft Support page](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2267427) it's also explained.

Comment: Yeah I know what VM is.. I just want to know how to see the equivalent value in Windows 7 process explorer.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is 'Commit Size'. It is easy to check. I have started a Java JVM and requested 1G of heap memory to be allocated at start up time. I can retrieve the 1G in the column 'Commit Size'.