# Garbage collection of inaccessible objects in loop

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection

If I have a loop such as this:

```
public class Foo {
     public Foo Foo;

     public Foo() {
     }
}

class Program {
    public static void Main(string[] args) {
         var foo = new Foo();
         long i = 0;
         while(i < Int64.MaxValue) {
             foo.Foo = new Foo();
             foo = foo.Foo;
             if(i % 10000 == 0)
                 GC.Collect();
             i++;
         }
         GC.Collect();
    }
}
```

The garbage collector will not clean up the parent objects until the loop is exited. Why is that? I don't see any way to reference them from the code once `foo` is reassigned, so shouldn't they be cleaned up?

I was looking at the memory usage of the process in Task Manager after passing some breakpoints I had set to determine this was happening. It keeps going up inside the loop (up to multi-GB if I make it infinite), but drops immediately when the loop quits and the second GC.Collect() is called.

Comment: What "parent objects"?

Comment: "The garbage collector will not clean up the parent objects until the loop is exited" : can you describe in your question how you are making those observations ?

Comment: I realise this is not your real code, but why not just do `foo = new Foo()` instead of assigning to `foo.Foo`? By the way, `Public Foo  Foo;` doesn't compile.

Comment: What is the name of the column your are looking at in the Task manager ?

Comment: @quantdev The column is Memory (Private Working Set)

Comment: you should never be looking at "Memory (Private Working Set)" in the Task Manager for such investigations., you should look at "Commit Size".

Comment: @Blorgbeard I just banged this out from what I remembered trying. I don't have the exact code I tried in front of me right now. I'm not really trying to solve any particular issue here, just trying to understand how the GC works better so I don't get tripped up later.

Comment: @quantdev This question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7954781/whats-the-difference-between-working-set-and-commit-size states that the Private Working Set indicates the physical memory usage, rather than the Commit Size, which is virtual. Isn't that what I want to track?

Comment: @joelises Maybe, but Just because the GC released the resources does not mean the CLR released the memory back to the OS. It may keep the memory allocated and put it in to a pool for later allocation requests of other new objects. Don't forget .NET programs run inside the Common Language Runtime (CLR) and a lot happens at the CLR level that has nothing to do with your program.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a slightly modified program that demonstrates the behavior more clearly:

```
class Foo
{
    public int Value;
    public Foo Next;

    public Foo(int value) { this.Value = value; Console.WriteLine("Created " + this.Value); }
    ~Foo() { Console.WriteLine("Finalized " + this.Value); }
}

class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var foo = new Foo(0);
        for (int value = 1; value < 50; ++value)
        {
            foo.Next = new Foo(value);
            foo = foo.Next;
            if (value % 10 == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Collecting...");
                GC.Collect();
                Thread.Sleep(10);
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Exiting");
    }
}
```

On .NET 4.5, when I build in Debug mode **AND** target Any CPU or x86, I reproduce the behavior you're seeing: the instances aren't finalized until after "Exiting" is printed. But when I build in Release mode **OR** target x64 (even when building in Debug mode), the instances are finalized as soon as they're unreachable:

```
Created 0
Created 1
Created 2
Created 3
Created 4
Created 5
Created 6
Created 7
Created 8
Created 9
Created 10
Collecting...
Finalized 9
Finalized 0
Finalized 8
Finalized 7
Finalized 6
Finalized 5
Finalized 4
Finalized 3
Finalized 2
Finalized 1
Created 11
Created 12
Created 13
...
```

Why does this happen? I suppose only a CLR expert can tell us for sure, but here's my guess: the behavior depends on specific details of the machine code that the JIT compiler and optimizer happen to generate, details which vary based on the target instruction set and whether you're running in debug mode. (Furthermore, these details may well change in future versions of the runtime.) In particular, in the x86/Debug case, I think the first `Foo(0)` instance gets stashed in a register or stack variable that *never gets overwritten in the rest of the method*; this initial instance keeps the entire chain alive. In the x86/Release and x64 cases, I think that due to JIT optimizations, the *same* register or stack variable is reused for every instance, thus releasing the initial instance.

Comment: Any more information on *how/why* the behavior differs in Debug mode?

Comment: @user2864740 the compiler/JIT generates extra temporaries to aid in debugging. You wouldn't want your locals collected while you were looking at them in the Watch window.

Comment: True .. but it seems like it'd need to store a collection (not just one or two extra temps/objects) to keep the strong reachability of the objects in this case :|

Comment: Since the instances are linked, it only needs to store a reference to `Foo(0)`. However, I don't know how or why it does so. Changing the loop to simply `foo = new Foo(value);` causes all the instances to be collected immediately, even in Debug mode.

Comment: I also noticed that the memory continues to grow in Release mode when launched with the debugger attached, so the JIT is definitely involved.

Comment: @MichaelLiu I'd be interested in finding out why it does that too. I had suspected it had something to do with debug, but why in this particular instance doesn't make any sense, since there would be no way that I could think of to reference it from the watch or anywhere else.

Comment: @joelises: I suspect that, with optimizations turned off, there just happens to be a reference to `Foo(0)` in an unused register or stack variable. See my updated answer.